# Is there a fast way to see if a method is wired/bound from any xib file in my project ?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Is there a fast way to see if a method is wired/bound from any xib file in my project ?

In other terms, I need to know if I can get rid of such method or it is used in Interface Builder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that `XCode` has a filter for bound `IBActions`. So I guess we're left with 2 possible solutions:

1. **Visually identify bound methods** (here I did a search for `IBAction`. Bound actions are denoted with a filled circle, while unbound actions are empty circles). Although this method works, it's not very useful when you have a lot of connections going on.
   [image]
2. **Parse the `xml` produced by interface builder**. If you take a look at the `xib` / `storyboard` files, you will see that there are `<connections>` tags with `<action>` children similar to this: `<action selector="fingeroff:" destination="ars-ip-845" eventType="touchDragOutside" id="1Nx-xZ-K1I"/>`, where `selector` is your method signature. I guess you could parse those xmls and make a list of the bound methods (also a nice idea for an app!)

If anyone though has a better way for dealing with this problem, please share!